# Find offers that can be matched with bids

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I am working on a sql query for the following scenario:

> Get all available offers for registered demand (offers from profiles
> should not be from profile which had registered demand). After that
> get all available offers from this initial profile which match any
> demand from any other profile.

I ended up with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM test_db_swap.Service 
        WHERE offer = 1
            AND profileId != 3622
            AND title LIKE('%Software%')
    ) AS offers
LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL
    (
        SELECT q1.id as Q1Id, q2.id as Q2Id, q1.title as Q1Title, q2.title as Q2Title, q1.profileId as Q1ProfileId, q2.profileId as Q2ProfileId
        FROM
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM test_db_swap.Service
            WHERE 
                (
                    offer = 1
                    AND profileId = 3622
                )
        ) as q1
        INNER JOIN LATERAL
        (   
            SELECT *
            FROM test_db_swap.Service
            WHERE 
                (
                    offer = 0
                    AND profileId != 3622
                    AND title LIKE(q1.title)
                ) 
        ) q2
        ON q1.title = q2.title
    ) AS giveBack
ON offers.profileId = giveBack.Q2ProfileId
```

I will need a pagination for this query, but I think I will do it with `LIMIT 20,40;` clause. My main concern is performance overhead due multiple subqueries and multiple joins. It should not be a big issue when I will add a pagination, but anyway.

Also engineering perfection - how it can be done better, - is my concern too as DBA is not my specialisation.

Thank you in advance.

Table schema:
`id | title | expirationDate | offer | index | profileId`

```
'12206', 'Software Development', '1673965266401', '1', NULL, '3621'
'12208', 'Consulting', '1673965266401', '1', NULL, '3621'
'12209', 'Product management', '1673965266401', '1', NULL, '3621'
'12210', 'Product management', '1673965266401', '1', NULL, '3622'
'12211', 'Product management', '1673965266401', '0', NULL, '3621'
'12212', 'Consulting', '1673965266401', '1', NULL, '3622'
'12213', 'Software Development', '1673965266401', '0', NULL, '3622'
```

EXPLAIN SELECT:
`id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra`

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'Service', NULL, 'ALL', 'fk_id', NULL, NULL, NULL, '7', '14.29', 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'Service', NULL, 'ALL', 'fk_id', NULL, NULL, NULL, '7', '100.00', 'Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'Service', NULL, 'ALL', 'fk_id', NULL, NULL, NULL, '7', '100.00', 'Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)'
```

Comment: Excuse me, I can not find a more explanatory title and introduction compare to what I already shared. The business use case is to **find all matches to registered demand and find out something within my own registered offers that can be used in exchange**. Here is the repository of the project for more details about business use case https://github.com/Gelassen/swap

Comment: I've edited that summary into the title for you (you could easily have done that yourself). Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have. To help get better reviews, also follow the advice in the [tag:sql] help: include your table and index definitions in the review.

Comment: Thank you, title still a bit different from my question, but let it be if it seems more meaningful for you as a potential reviewer.

Comment: Sadly, I'm insufficiently skilled in SQL to be a reviewer myself; I'm just trying to help you get good reviews from those who can.  The best titles give a user's perspective of the functionality the code provides; if you can improve on my understanding of what it achieves, please edit further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to see how this could be a performant query.

```
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM test_db_swap.Service 
        WHERE offer = 1
            AND profileId != 3622
            AND title LIKE('%Software%')
    ) AS offers
LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
```

I am assuming that cardinality of `offer` is low,
cardinality of `profileId` is high,
and `3622` is just an example which will
change from query to query.
Given a million distinct profile IDs,
we might have roughly a three million row table.

Put another way, a WHERE profileId = NNN query will enjoy very good
[selectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_selection_factor).

I assume we have an index available on `profileId`,
and another on `title`.

I am sad that you did not include any COUNT(*)
or EXPLAIN PLAN output in the question.

---

Let's look at those three conjuncts.
We're filtering on `offer`, fine, it cannot be usefully indexed,
as it takes on just a handful of distinct values.
We're table scanning for all mismatched profile IDs,
filtering out the handful of matches.
And we're similarly table scanning / filtering
for `title`, since the leading `%` wildcard
prevents MariaDB / Mysql from exploiting a title index.

Sounds bad.

Every paginated query is going to have to perform
a full table scan, every single time.
Even if all rows fit in the cache, you're
going to burn CPU cycles examining all rows
every single time.
This is independent of examining what the
rest of the query does.

---

Further down we see this:

```
                    AND title LIKE(q1.title)
```

That is definitely sub-optimal.
Prefer an equality check, rather than `LIKE`.
So there's some potential for the query
planner to exploit a title index.

A conjunct of AND title LIKE X,
where the planner can see the literal text of X,
may or may not use an index depending on wildcard
characters in X seen by the planner.
When X comes from query rows, then all such bets are off.

```
            AND title LIKE('%Software%')
```

Consider using mysql
[full text](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)
indexing, with the MATCH keyword.
Postgres also has
[excellent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html)
support for such queries.

Better still, do some analysis up-front to simplify the query.

Table scan *once* to obtain all DISTINCT titles,
storing the result in a table or in memory.
Filter those titles to obtain the software-related titles,
maybe one or a half dozen such titles.
Pose the conjunct as: AND title IN ('this', 'that', 'other');

That way the planner will request just a handful of index probes,
rather than a full scan.

Given the apparent low cardinality of `title`,
this probably isn't a very interesting aspect to optimize.

---

For predictable output,
you probably want to include an ORDER BY.
Especially if you plan to paginate.

---

Let's say that table scanning is "too expensive"
for interactive production queries.

The query in its current form can't really be saved.
It requires table scan, every time. (Or at least a full
index scan given a
[covering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index)
index, which would be the moral equivalent.)

Assuming that UPDATE / INSERTs which materially affect query
results will happen "infrequently",
you will need to store results indexed by profile ID
in a MATERIALIZED VIEW. Then do some (cheap) filtering
on `title` at query time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply here. ```profileId``` and ```title``` (profile vs service) has ```1..N``` relationship. Yes, services might have duplications but due expiration date column each service row likely would be unique, which makes it cardinality higher rather than profile rows. In terms of cardinality within the same table ```profileId``` still would have less unique numbers rather than ```title``` column or at least equal counts - ```column``` has higher or equal cardinality compare with ```profileId```.

Comment: You didn't mention the format of ```PARTIAL TABLE``` you are interested in, so I share it within JSON format https://paste.ofcode.org/FX2iRHccgJzWg2apcA9mku. Thank you for mentioned this, I haven't used this tool before (my major specialisation is android development).

Comment: ```COUNT()``` is not important here as test database has just a dozen of rows. Performance test hasn't been done yet, but I keep it in mind when I started this post.

Comment: ```WHERE profileId = NNN``` I used it where it is possible, but my use case requires to have non-equality operator unless you or other code reviewer knows a better solution. The use case of this subquery is by given _profile id_ select all offers which doesn't belong to this _profile id_.

Comment: Does ```MATCH .. AGAINST``` have better performance rather than ```LIKE``` on partial search ```%keyword%```? I familiar with ```MATCH```, but had an opinion ```LIKE``` is better in performance terms.

Comment: Unfortunately, modification of tables by end users are frequent, a product at its 1st iteration allows to limit modifications at least once per 24 hours and will return back to indexation when I faced with the necessity to squeeze maximum performance from db operations. At this moment database sharding looks as a better alternative. I like the idea to prefilter rows by ```DISTINCT``` titles and do the search by them. ```Views``` and ```MViews``` was told can not support outer joins, so I will need to think how to better to do this. ```ORDER BY```, ```MATCH``` also could be used here.